# VSCode Extension Show Functions

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode extension: [Show Functions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qrti.funclist).

How to extend filter setting for usage on .prg files. I would like to filter all
PROCEDURE in file.

```
{
    "extensions": [
        ".prg"
    ],
    "native": "/^(PROCEDURE|procedure) ?",
    "display": "/^(PROCEDURE|procedure) ?",
    "sort": 0
}
```

I expect in side window all Procedure and name of procedure

Comment: Could you please post what happened when you tried your approach? Is this a specific question about syntax inside VSCode not behaving like you expect?

Comment: I am fairly good at RegEx, but I recommend testing your Regular Expression at https://regex101.com/, and then prepare it for the JSON file by properly escaping all the characters that need escaping at https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html

I couldn't get mine right until I used both of these web pages to test and validate.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** you have a .`prg` file that looks something like this:

```
PROCEDURE DecryptUser
LPARAM lcUser
LOCAL Cadena_1
Cadena_1 = ""

   For i = 1 to Len(TRIM(lcUser)) STEP 2
       Cadena_1 = Cadena_1 + CHR(VAL(SUBSTR(lcUser, i, 2))-4)
   Next

RETURN Cadena_1

procedure DecryptPwd
LPARAM lcPwd
LOCAL Cadena_2
Cadena_2 = ""

   For i = 1 to Len(TRIM(lcPwd)) STEP 2
       Cadena_2 = Cadena_2 + CHR(VAL(SUBSTR(lcPwd, i, 2))+5)
   Next

RETURN Cadena_2
```

use in your settings:

```
"funcList": {
    "doubleSpacing": true,
    "filters": [
      {
        "extensions": [
          ".prg",
        ],

        // lower and upper case will be captured with I flag
        "native": "/^PROCEDURE\\s+\\w+/mgi",

        // show everything captured in native filter (no modification)
        "display": "/.*/",

        // show only the procedure names, not preceded by "PROCEDURE"
        "display": "/\\w+(\\s+\\w+)/1",

        "sort": 0
      }
    ]
  }
```

produces this output:

```
PROCEDURE DecryptUser

procedure DecryptPwd
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support and idea.
Trying your sample prg worked as described.
It will not work with my code for some reason.
My code looks like this for example:

define class ...
procedure one ...
endproc

procedure two ...
endproc

procedure ..
endproc
enddefine

define class ..
define procedure ...
endproc
...
...
enddefine

Because of the many procedure's 
it would be very helpful to have the 
show function working

Regards ulli

Answer (score 0):

After playing arround this did it for me:

{
                    "extensions": [
                      ".prg",
                    ],

```
                // lower and upper case will be captured with I flag
                "native": "/PROCEDURE\\s+\\S+/mgi",

                // show everything captured in native filter (no modification)
                "display": "/.*/",

                // show only the procedure names, not preceded by "PROCEDURE"
                //"display": "/\\w+(\\s+\\w+)/1",

                "sort": 0
        }
```

regards ulli